# How to use proxy, reflect with Map collection

Tags: javascript, typescript

I heard `Map` collection has `[[MapData]]` internal slot, so i need to use `Reflect` to trap.

So i write a code like below

```js
const map = new Map();

const proxiedMap = new Proxy(map, {
 get(target, property, receiver) {
  const currentValue = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
  return typeof currentValue === "function" ? currentValue.bind(target) : currentValue;
 }
});
```

This code works well when i call `set` and `get`, however when i call `size`, the error occurs.

```js
proxiedMap.set("a", 1);
proxiedMap.get("a"); // 1
console.log(proxiedMap.size) // TypeError: Method get Map.prototype.size called on incompatible receiver #<Map>
```

I solved the problem omit `receiver` argument in Reflect. But i don't the reason why it works.

```js
const proxiedMap = new Proxy(map, {
  get(target, property) {
    const currentValue = Reflect.get(target, property)
    return typeof currentValue === "function" ? currentValue.bind(target) : currentValue
  }
})
```

Why it happens only use `size`?

Answer (score 1):

The `receiver` argument in Proxy#get is *the proxy itself*

```
const proxiedMap = new Proxy(map, {
 get(target, property, receiver) {
  console.log(receiver === proxiedMap)
 }
}
```

And the `receiver` of `Reflect.get` is `this` to use for getter

```
function Reflect_get(target, property, receiver = target) {
  let descriptor = Object.getPropertyDescriptor(target, property)
  if (descriptor.get) return descriptor.get.apply(receiver)
  else return receiver[property]
}
```

so you error by calling `get Map#size` on `proxiedMap` which is not a Map

---

In your case, you don't need to `bind`, as `this` will be implied as the proxy anyways
And you may want `class extends Map` rather then `Proxy<Map>`

Comment: thanks, but i don't know why `map.get` and `map.set` work with receiver in Reflect